# Axis 2 Exception while generating java code of a WCF Webservice

Tags: wcf, web-services, axis

I've a web service created using WCF. It uses CustomException as well.

When i use Axis 2 to generate java code from it (WSDL2JAVA) it thorws the following error:

```
>     IWAB0399 Error in generating java from WSDL
>     Missing <soap:fault> element inFault Operation "CustomExceptionFault" in operation "CustomExceptionFault", in binding
> GetPDFs
>     java.io.IOException: ERROR: Missing <soap:fault> element inFault "CustomExceptionFault" in operation "CustomExceptionFault", in binding
> GetPDFs at
> org.apache.axis.wsdl.symbolTable.SymbolTable.faultFromSOAPFault(Unknown
> Source)
```

My WSDL snippet

```
<wsdl:binding name="tdsServiceSoap12" type="tns:ITDSService">
<soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="GetPDFs">
<soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/ITDSService/GetPDFs" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
<wsdl:fault name="CustomExceptionFault">
<soap12:fault name="CustomExceptionFault" use="literal"/>
</wsdl:fault>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
```

Hope it clarifies. If need further information please let me know.

Regards

Comment: The stack trace and error message indicates that you are using Axis 1.x, not Axis2.

Comment: awww. will it be an issue.? actually i am WCF developer, and my client send me this issue. and he reported it saying he is using Axis 2...

Comment: Yes, Axis2 is a complete rewrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article helped me solve my problem with some other tweaks.

http://weblogs.asp.net/pglavich/archive/2010/03/16/making-wcf-output-a-single-wsdl-file-for-interop-purposes.aspx